# Why I can't convert source type to string even though explicit operator is created?

Tags: c#, casting

I have a very simple class:

```
public class MyCustomBoolean {
    private bool _value = false;

    public MyCustomBoolean(bool value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public bool value => _value;


    #region casting support

    public static explicit operator string(MyCustomBoolean m) {
        return m.value.ToString();
    }

    public static explicit operator bool(MyCustomBoolean m) {
        return m.value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And now, somewhere in my code I try to:

```
public void someMethod(MyCustomBoolean param) {
    string testString = param;
}
```

The error I keep getting is:
`cannot convert source type MyCustomBoolean to type string`

I have a few classes handling different types but this one is the only one causing me trouble.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't see any explicit cast there. Can you show your other classes that work?

Comment: Yeah, I have messed up the base... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to use an `explicit` operator as an `implicit` one.
The following should work:

```
public void someMethod(MyCustomBoolean param) {
    string testString = (string)param; // explicit cast to string
}
```

If you wanted to use the code the way it was written, you would need to instead define conversion operators as `implicit`, like so:

```
public static implicit operator string(MyCustomBoolean m) {
    return m.value.ToString();
}

public static implicit operator bool(MyCustomBoolean m) {
    return m.value;
}
```

At which point, your previous code will work as expected.

```
public void someMethod(MyCustomBoolean param) {
    string testString = param; // implicit cast
}
```

Comment: Dammit. I have made the mistake at the beginning and it only surfaced with the `bool` type. I am at the beginning of the refactoring so I probably didn't get to the Dates etc.

Comment: @Krystian I'd exercise caution if you plan to make a lot of your conversions implicit. It can make it very unclear what's going on in code when types are constantly converting themselves.

Comment: thanks for the tip. The purpose of the classes is to convert from using Dictionaries with objects where a type was determined by some string. In the end, the code was always doing explicit casting all the time. Refactoring and maintenance of that code is tedious so I hope to make it easier now.